# How to post data to razor page code behind asp.net core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to implement a bulk operation function, but I cannot post my data to the razor page code behind, anyone can help? Please check my code below

```
 <form method="post" asp-page="./Index">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="margin-top:15px;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="info">
                                <th></th>
                                <th>
                                    <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.NumberSort">
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].Number)
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products[0].Name)
                                </th>                            
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Checked)
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="success">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                    </td>                                  
                                    <td>
                                        <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-info">details</a>
                                        <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-warning">edit</a>
                                        <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">    
                    @{
                        var items = Model.Products.Where(x => x.Checked);
                    }
                    <input type="submit" name="bulkUpload" value="bulk upload" asp-route-data="@items"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>


 public async Task OnPostAsync(List<Product> upload)
        {
        }
```

Comment: You mean a controller, not code-behing, right? You're using ASP.NET MVC, right?

Comment: @RuiJarimba No, I don't have controller, I use asp.net core razor pages project template

Answer (score 0):

You need to render your products in such way that the Modelbinder will be able to pick them up on form submit and pass them into the codebehind.

Something like this (done by hand so it might not compile at first):

```
@{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Model.Produtcs[i].Checked" />
        @Model.Products[i].Number
        @Model.Products[i].Name
    }
}
```

This will render HTML like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Products[0].Checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Products[1].Checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Products[2].Checked" />
```

And it should get back to your OnPostAsync. If not then try changing

```
public async Task OnPostAsync(List<Product> upload)
```

to

```
public async Task OnPostAsync(YourModel model)
```

What ever your full model is named.

This is then redundant:

```
@{
    var items = Model.Products.Where(x => x.Checked);
}
```